# Ubuntu 18.04 Bluetooth mouse very laggy

Tags: 18.04, mouse, bluetooth

This question seems to have been asked a few times but there are no answers so I thought I would ask again.

Usually I use my wireless trackball (Kensington Expert Wireless Trackball) with the included dongle but today I left it in my other laptop.

So I thought I'd try the Bluetooth connection; it is very slow / laggy when using the Bluetooth vs the dongle.

Bluetooth card:

```
adam@adamWork:~$ lspci | grep -i wire
6e:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

DMESG shows:

```
adam@adamWork:~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    4.695603] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.695617] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.695620] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.695621] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.695625] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.820710] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
[    4.821677] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[    4.821677] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    4.821678] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    4.821678] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    4.821678] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    4.821679] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    4.836195] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-12-16.sfi
[    6.166487] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    6.166640] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1314684 usecs
[    6.166669] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    6.178644] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 11701 usecs
[    6.239556] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-12-16.ddc
[    6.242683] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[    6.311055] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.311056] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.311059] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   26.025442] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   26.025454] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   26.025510] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 2882.091751] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2915.114830] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2931.129683] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2946.999706] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2963.245791] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2980.138690] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2991.927036] hid-generic 0005:047D:8019.0001: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v0.01 Mouse [Expert Wireless TB] on 00:28:F8:51:7C:3B
```

So it is showing as a hdi (human interface device) and as a mouse on the GUI tool.

Interestingly the scroll wheel seems to work as normal as do the buttons; it is just the mouse movement that is lagging.

This is a minor issue for me as when I get home I will just move the dongle back to this computer; however it seems that others are asking the same question but not getting good answers.